# Image background already changing, can I fit it to browser window and make fade in and out

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, timed

Hello below is my JS code for a changing background image every 30 seconds. could somebody please advise me if there is a way to alter the code to fit the image to the browser window (100%) and also if there is any JS that I could use within this code to make the images fade in and out seemlessly and elegantly.

```
<script>
bgArr = ['images/bg1.jpg', 'images/bg2.jpg', 'images/bg3.jpg'];
bgCur = 0;
backgroundSwitch = function()
{
if (bgCur == bgArr.length) bgCur = 0;
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ bgArr[bgCur++]+ ')';
}
window.setInterval(backgroundSwitch, 30000); // Switch every 30 seconds.
</script>
```

Thank you everybody

Comment: could you show me how to do both the fade in and the fit to window just in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 introduced `background-size: cover`. This automatically sizes the background image to **cover** the entire parent element, either scaling it horizontally or vertically to fill.

See the entry on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

`background-size` is supported by all major browsers.

Comment: `cover`, even better :)

Answer (score 0):

Fitting to browser window should be simple enough. Depending on your browser requirements, you might be able to get away with `background-size: cover` in your CSS (see [Albert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21209574/31671)).

As for animating, you could either use CSS transitions and trigger them via JavaScript (generally by modifying the class) or use JavaScript to do it.

If using JavaScript, be sure to set a duration and then [lerp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) (or some other method) between the states.

This is the general idea...

```
var img = document.getElementById("fade");

var fadeLength = 5500;
var opacity = 0;
var startTime = Date.now();

requestAnimationFrame(function me() { 
    // It's faded in, stop animating!
    if (opacity >= 1) {
       return;   
    }

    opacity = (Date.now() - startTime) / fadeLength;
    img.textContent = opacity;    
    img.style.opacity = opacity;        
    requestAnimationFrame(me);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxuZC/).

Comment: could you show me how to do both the fade in and the fit to window just in Javascript?

Comment: @user3206866 Working on it now :)

Comment: Hi, thanks, sorry for being stupid but how does this fit into my current code, I;m just learning all this and I don't see how it fits.

Comment: @user3206866 It's meant to be a basic starting point to learn from. The idea is to use time offsets to animate, in order to achieve an animation being represented independent of computer speed/screen update.